# Multiple GCC versions in ELF comments

Tags: linux, gcc, binary-files

I'm trying to determine what version of GCC was used to compile various executables.  To do this I'm looking at the comment section of ELF files.  I assumed I would always only come across a single GCC version, however I got the following output.

```
GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
GCC: (GNU) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
```

What would cause there to be three GCC comments and two separate versions?

NOTE: This file is found within a python wheel

Comment: Perhaps the modules that are linked into the one executable were not all compiled by the same GCC (which is very bad practice of course).

Comment: @harrymc This was my first thought too

Comment: I would think that it's likely that some of these modules may have as origin from older static linked libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate a similar situation on a centos/devtoolset-7-perftools-centos7 by installing devtoolset-6 and running:

```
$ /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wall test.c
$ strings -a a.out | grep "GCC: ("
GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)
```

This might be a bug with how the comment is generated because the expected output is just the second line